# lookup/map multiple keys in a dictionary and add to a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My current code:

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag, map_tag
search_term = 'quaker lemon banana oatmeal'
lst = []
search_term_words = search_term.split()
for w in search_term_words:
  if w in flavor_grocer_mapping:
      for flavor in flavor_grocer_mapping[w]:
          if flavor in search_term:
              lst.append((flavor, 'FLAVOR'))
              for x in search_term.replace(flavor, '').split(): 
                  if x in brand_grocer_mapping:
                      for brand in brand_grocer_mapping[x]:
                          if brand in search_term.replace(flavor, '').split():
                              lst.append((brand, 'BRAND'))
                              for word, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(search_term.replace(flavor, '').replace(brand, '').strip())):
                                  lst.append((word, map_tag('en-ptb', 'universal', tag)))
```

The result I got:

```
[('lemon', 'FLAVOR'), 
 ('quaker', 'BRAND'),
 ('banana', 'NOUN'), 
 ('oatmeal', 'NOUN'),
 ('banana', 'FLAVOR'),
 ('quaker', 'BRAND'),
 ('lemon', 'ADJ'),
 ('oatmeal', 'NOUN')]
```

My expected result is:

```
[('lemon', 'FLAVOR'),
 ('banana', 'FLAVOR'),
 ('quaker', 'BRAND'),
 ('oatmeal', 'NOUN')]
```

I know the problem is that the splitted words in search terms run recursively in the for loops. How can lookup/map a whole string that contains multiple keys in a dictionary? (For example, `lemon` and `banana` are in the search term string and they are the keys in the `flavor_grocer_mapping` dictionary.)

Comment: Not sure if I understood your requirement. Can you please simplify the requirement, with example inputs and outputs.

Comment: It is probably caused by your nested loops which I think would be not required. It seems you are mapping them based on `flavor_grocer_mapping`, would you be able to show an example with that included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I tried to recreate `flavor_grocer_mapping` based on your results, your additional code to lookup is highly unnecessary. Instead, since you have a dictionary that corresponds to `search_term_words` as keys, do a proper dictionary lookup in a list comprehension.

```
search_term = 'quaker lemon banana oatmeal'
search_term_words = search_term.split()

#recreating your dictionary
flavor_grocer_mapping = [('lemon', 'FLAVOR'),
                         ('banana', 'FLAVOR'),
                         ('quaker', 'BRAND'),
                         ('oatmeal', 'NOUN')]
flavor_grocer_mapping = {k:v for (k,v) in flavor_grocer_mapping} 

#solution
results = [(word,flavor_grocer_mapping[word]) for word in search_term_words]
results
>>[('quaker', 'BRAND'),
 ('lemon', 'FLAVOR'),
 ('banana', 'FLAVOR'),
 ('oatmeal', 'NOUN')]
```

In the case of your provided example, I suggest your merge all the dictionaries to 1 instead of repeatedly looping over them.

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I took your advice and merge the two dictionaries into one by `favor_brand_dict = {** brand_grocer_mapping, ** flavor_grocer_mapping}`

Comment: No problem! Hope you found it useful. Performing a lookup from one source will always be much easier.